# Putting an image with a space in the filename inside of a Panel

Tags: panels, wysiwyg

We have images that are being uploaded with IMCE to our Drupal installation.  Some of these images have a space in the filename.  The ones with spaces in the filename work on normal content pages, but if we try to put them in a Panel (such as in a custom content section), the filename gets truncated up until the first space.

Example: Trying to insert this image inside of a panel:

```
"/sites/default/files/marketing/Annual%20Pricing%20image.png"
```

will result in the following code on the site:

```
<img alt="" src="/sites/default/files/marketing/Annual.png" style="width: 1200px; height: 128px;" />
```

Starting at the %20 for the space, the remainder of the filename gets cut off except for the file extension.

For reference, the source code from CKEditor inside of the panel:

```
<p>Good image:&nbsp;<img alt="" src="/sites/default/files/marketing/Adobe.png" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;" /></p>

<p>Bad image:&nbsp;<img alt="" src="/sites/default/files/marketing/Annual%20Pricing%20image.png" style="width: 1200px; height: 128px;" /></p>
```

Is there anything that I can do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: It looks like a bug that should be reported to the issue queue, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Weird. As a workaround (and general good practice) you can use the [Transliteration](https://drupal.org/project/transliteration) module to sanitize filename before they are uploaded.

Comment: @AdamBalsam wellll, even the module page for Translieration says "you may or may not want to use this ...". A "best practice" is a bit of a stretch. But, for sure a good stop-gap workaround for the bug.